# Where can I download the Java.Net install

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This may actually show how much of a Noobie I am but does anyone know where I can grab Java.net from?

I don't really like eclipse and would like a version integrated with my Visual Studio environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you are out of luck.  A few years back, Microsoft had their own non-standard version of Java (J++, and then J#), but they have been discontinued.  Also, they weren't compatible with the official Java spec so code wasn't portable to other machines/JVM's.

If you want to program Java and don't like Eclipse, check out either Netbeans (free) or IntelliJ (free limited version/full paid version).

Comment: Yeah I remember having J# a while ago.  It's not that we're actually going to use J# but we are trying to learn Java here and I thought that having it in a familiar environment might speed things up a tad.  Thanks for confirming the worst!  :)

Comment: Gotcha.  If you haven't taken a look at IntelliJ, it's made by the same folks who produce ReSharper for Visual Studio -- JetBrains.  It still feels a bit foreign coming from VS, but a very nice IDE for Java work.

Comment: That's why C# does exist in first place ( despite C# fan's say )

Comment: @OscarRyz we're about to embark on Endeca projects and require Java knowledge and skills so...

Comment: @griegs no, I mean, about the gbc answer, when MS was banned from continuing with J++ they launched C#. In retrospective that was the best thing that could happen to VB developers ;)